# Como obtener el valor de una variable de un archivo php desde un archivo js

Tags: php, javascript

deseo obtener el valor de la variable $verficacion que se encuentra en el siguiente archivo php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

include 'conexion_be.php';
$nombre_completo = $_POST['nombre_completo'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre_completo, correo,usuario, contrasena)
          VALUES('$nombre_completo','$correo','$usuario','$contrasena')";


//verificacion de datos repetidos

$verificar_correo = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo'");


$verificacion = mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo);

if($verificacion>0)
{
    echo ' <script>
    alert("El correo ya esta registrado");
    </script>
    ';
    
    
    exit();
}

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

la variable $verificación tiene un dato entero que me dice cuantos registros hay  en la base de datos de correo y necesito este valor para compararlo en el js y ejecutar  la funcion irA()

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      var nombre_completo=document.getElementById("nombre_completo").value;
      var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
      var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
      var contrasena = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;
      
      
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/registro_usuario_be.php",
      data: { "nombre_completo" :  nombre_completo ,"correo":correo, "usuario":usuario, "contrasena":contrasena},
      success: function(data){
 
      }
  });
    if("la variable que neceito de php">0)
    {
        alert("este correo ya esta registrado");          
        irA(registro);
    }else
    {
      irA(registroMascota);
    }
  
    });
```

necesito esta variable para poder verificar si el correo si esta registrado y saber a que sección enviar al usuario

Comment: Debes retornar los valores que necesitas en formato json, de ser posible. Y debes hacer una petición ajax hacia tu archivo php para capturar ese valor en el javascript

Comment: como podría hacer esta petición?

Comment: Esta pregunta es duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434896 ??

Comment: si amigo pero había formulado mal la pregunta por eso la subí de nuevo

Comment: Servidor (PHP) y cliente (Javascript), se comunican mediante peticiones HTTP. Dispones de la función `ajax()` en JQuery, o de la API `fetch` o del siempre confiable `XMLHttpRequest`, entre otras. Todas las peticiones las inicia el cliente (Javascript), y son respondidas por el servidor (PHP). Ahora, lo que debes hacer es implementar algún método de los ya mencionados y trabajar con el resultado de las solicitudes. Saludos

Comment: De hecho, en tu código ya casi lo tienes. Donde pone: `success: function(data) { ... }`. En esa función (y sólo dentro de esa función) tendrás acceso a la variable `data` que debe tener lo que envías desde PHP.