# ¿Como obtengo el valor de una variable en un archivo PHP desde un archivo JS?

Tags: php, javascript, script

Deseo obtener el valor de la variable verificación que se encuentra en un archivo php desde un js para hacer una verificacion de los datos obtenidos en esta variable.
Mi Php:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>e

include 'conexion_be.php';
$nombre_completo = $_POST['nombre_completo'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre_completo, correo,usuario, contrasena)
          VALUES('$nombre_completo','$correo','$usuario','$contrasena')";


//verificacion de datos repetidos

$verificar_correo = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo'");


$verificacion = mysqli_num_rows($verificar_correo);

echo json_encode(int $ver=$verificacion);

if($verificacion>0)
{
    echo ' <script>
    alert("El correo ya esta registrado");
    </script>
    ';
    
    
    exit();
}

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Necesito extraer el contenido de esta variable para poder verificar si la información que contiene es repetida, y proceder a cargar una pagina o volver a esa según el resultado de la validación.

Mi JS:

```
btn_enviar1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      var nombre_completo=document.getElementById("nombre_completo").value;
      var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
      var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
      var contrasena = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;
      
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/registro_usuario_be.php",
      data: { "nombre_completo" :  nombre_completo ,"correo":correo, "usuario":usuario, "contrasena":contrasena},
      success: function(data){
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
          
      }
  });
    if("la variable que neceito de php">0)
    {
        alert("este correo ya esta registrado");          
        irA(registro);
    }else
    {
      irA(registroMascota);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Quizá este link te ayude (te vienen varias formas de hacerlo :3): https://parzibyte.me/blog/2020/04/26/pasar-variable-php-javascript/

Comment: que por cierto, no hace falta crearse otro usuario para reformular la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434939/como-obtener-el-valor-de-una-variable-de-un-archivo-php-desde-un-archivo-js